# PostgreSQL sum typecasting as a bigint

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, aggregate-functions, bigint

I am doing the sum() of an integer column and I want to typecast the result to be a bigint - to avoid an error.  However when I try to use sum(myvalue)::bigint it still gives me an out of range error.

Is there anything that I can do to the query to get this to work?  Or do I have to change the column type to a bigint?

Comment: Try sum(myvalue::bigint)

Comment: `sum(myvalue)::bigint` means "calculate the aggregate function `sum` over `myvalue`, then cast the result of that to `bigint`" - so by the time the cast happens, `sum()` has already chosen its result type.

Comment: From the doc, sum returns `bigint for smallint or int arguments, numeric for bigint arguments, double precision for floating-point arguments, otherwise the same as the argument data type`, so the internal cast may not be necessary anyway. Realistically, the number of rows it would take for a sum of ints to overflow bigint would likely fail on other things first (like disk space, IO bandwidth, etc...). Although I have seen a few fringe cases where it actually does overflow.

Answer (score 5):

The [current manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) is more explicit than it used to be in 2013:

> `sum` ( `integer` ) → `bigint`

If your column `myvalue` indeed has the type `integer` like you say, then the result is `bigint` anyway, and the added cast in `sum(myvalue)::bigint` is just noise.

Either way, to get an "out of range"  error, the result would have to be bigger than what [`bigint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) can hold:

> -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807

One would have to aggregate a *huge* number of big `integer` values (>= 2^32 * 2^31). If so, cast the base column to `bigint`, thereby forcing the result to be `numeric`:

```
SELECT sum(myvalue::int8) ...
```

The more likely explanation is that your column has, in fact, a different data type, or the error originates from something else. Not enough detail in the question.

Comment: Good guess, but I should have specified that the values were within the bigint range.

Comment: @AaronKreider: Generally you should provide the table definition (what you get from psql with `\d mytable`) and be more specific. "The values" is still ambiguous ...

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using following statement

```
SUM(CAST(gross_amount AS Integer))
```

This is give the result of the column as SUm bigint,

Note:My column gross_amount was double type.

Comment: If the `sum (gross_amount)` is out of range for `bigint`, but `SUM(CAST(gross_amount AS Integer))` is not, then the cast must have truncated values, leading to false results. Besides, highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it *before* doing the operation:

```
SUM(myvalue::bigint)
```